# How do I open / manipulate multiple files in bash?

Tags: bash, unix, outputstream

I have a bash script that take advantage of a local toolbox to perform an operation
my question is fairly simple

I have multiple files that are the same quantities but different time steps i would like to first untar them all, and then use the toolbox to perform some manipulation but i am not sure if i am on the right track.

=============================================

The file is as follows

INPUTS

```
fname = a very large number or files with same name but numbering
e.g wnd20121.grb
    wnd20122.grb
      .......
    wnd2012100.grb
```

COMMANDS

```
> cdo -f nc copy fname ofile(s)
```

(If this is the ofile(s)=output file how can i store it for sequent use ? Take the ofile (output file) from the command and use it / save it as input to the next, producing a new subsequent numbered output set of  ofile(s)2)

```
>cdo merge ofile(s) ofile2
```

(then automatically take the ofile(s)2 and input them to the next command and so on, producing always an array of new output files with specific set name I set but different numbering for distinguishing them)

```
>cdo sellon ofile(s)2  ofile(s)3
```

### ------------------------------------

To make my question clearer, I would like to know the way in which I can instruct basically through a bash script the terminal to "grab" multiple files that are usually the same name but have a different numbering to make the separate their recorded time

e.g.  file1 file2 ...file n

and then get multiple outputs , with every output corresponding to the number of the file it converted.

e.g. output1 output2 ...outputn

How can I set these parameters so the moment they are generated they are stored for subsequent use in the script, in later commands?

Comment: What have you done till now? Please post your **try** to solve this..

Comment: @Jord i have written the sequence, the first parts , i think after that i can extend the logic of multiple loads and save to the rest of the scripts, but i start with these

Comment: are you really using `... **wnd10m.gdas.2010*.grb2**    ***ofile***` on the cmd line? Multiple `*` on the cmd-line are the same as single `*` chars. Rewrite as `**wnd10m.gdas.2010*.grb2*    *ofile*` (which still seems unlikely).  Don't confuse the issue with this sort of "noise" in your question. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter No i m not using them , i was requested to paste the code so i did but used the bold typing here to underline the files I am interested in , i will correct the format i am using so it more clear

Comment: Sorry, but it's hard to tell what is going on here, as I don't know what `cdo` does. Consider editing this down to 1 question with simple definitions of what you are using. Don't try to make it a list of questions. Also, your code `> fname.grib = ' wnd10m.gdas*.grb2   '` seems suspect. Allowing that `fname.grib =` is a valid `cdo` construct, it seems unusual that something labeled as a file has a bunch of spaces at the end. Do you mean `>fname.grib = 'wnd10m.gdas*.grb2'` ? Don't answer here, use this feedback to improve your next question. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter i have modified the question to make it clearer

Comment: Your edit would make one good question. BUT your detail about how this works is (for me) impossible to understand. If you make a question like the following, it will greatly increase your chances of help -------- 1. I have this current situation (sample input data), in your case, `ls -l file1 file2 ... file* ` (is there other info you need to include here?). 2. I need to create the following output from the inputs in step 1. 3. My current script looks like  .... 4. my current output from my script looks like .... 5. I don't like this output because .... . Good luck.

Comment: In your current edit/example, are you saying that `file1` should be renamed as `output1`, etc, etc? Do `cdo` or `time` have anything to do with your problem? If not, remove it from you **NEW** question ; -) ... Good luck!

Comment: @shellter the time and cdo are irrelevant to the issue, tried to re-phrase the question hope its more clear now

Comment: Getting better, but why did you leave the first mention of `ofile2 =` empty. Are you indicating that it starts out empty and then for each file, you want to set the variable `ofile2` so that `cdo` can use it? OR given that you mention `ofile(s)`, do you intend that `ofile` "builds up" a list, like `ofile="file1 file2 ... filen"` ? Please continue to edit your question, don't answer these questions as a comment.

Comment: @shellter my mistake the ofile2 at the start...
what i am pursuing is the generated files from one command to be passed as input files to another, producing new output files until i reach the end of my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, but perhaps the following will help; it demonstrates how to use arrays as argument lists and how to parse command output into an array, line by line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Create the array of input files using pathname expansion.
inFiles=(wnd*.grb)

# Pass the input-files array to another command and read its output
# - line by line - into a new array, `outFiles`.
# The example command here simply prepends 'out' to each element of the 
# input-files array and outputs each (modified) element on its own line.
# Note: The assumption is that the filenames have no embedded newlines
# (which is usually true).
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a outFiles < \
  <(printf "%s\n" "${inFiles[@]}" | sed s'/^/out-/')

# Note: If you use bash 4, you could use `readarray -t outFiles < <(...)` instead.

# Output the resulting array.
# This also demonstrates how to use an array as an argument list 
# to pass to _any_ command.
printf "%s\n" "${outFiles[@]}"
```

Comment: thank you very much seems that this may help me basically "loop" over the processes